# Titanium Project: Push notification without ArrowPush

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, firebase-cloud-messaging, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I can successfully retrieve the device token but don't know the next step in order to receive notification sent from Firebase console. 
Seems those appcelerator documents on push notification are all talking about using ArrowPush.

Any hint?